# How to check if a field was initialized or contains the default value in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I'm mapping a json string to a class using jackson mapper. The class looks like this:

```
class MyClass{      
    @JsonProperty("my_boolean")
    private boolean myBoolean;

    @JsonProperty("my_int")
    private int myInt;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

I want to check if the fields myBoolean and myInt were actually set or contain their default values (false and 0). I tried using reflection and checking if the field was null, but I guess that won't work for primitive types. This is what I have now:

```
Field[] fields = myClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {            
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object myObject = field.get(myClass);
                if(myObject != null) {
                  //Thought this would work, but it doesn't
                }
            }
         }
```

How else can I check this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to distinguish between a "default" value of, say, `false` and a `false` value set as a result of the annotation?  That is impossible.

Comment: Create a new Object of that class (which will have default values). Then compare field by field with existing Object.

Comment: You'll need to get a reference to a wrapper for the default value of each primitive type and use `equals`.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar: Reflection works perfectly well for primitives, so long as you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

You should check whether the field type is primitive, and if it is, check the value against a default wrapper. For example:

```
Map<Class, Object> defaultValues = new HashMap<Class, Object>();
defaultValues.put(Integer.class, Integer.valueOf(0)); 
// etc - include all primitive types
```

Then:

```
Object value = field.get(myClass);
if (value == null ||
    (field.getType().isPrimitive() && value.equals(defaultValues.get(field.getType())) {
   // Field has its default value
}
```

That won't tell whether the field has been set or not - only whether its current value is the default value for the type. You can't tell the difference between a field which has a value of 0 because it's been explicitly set that way and one which hasn't been explicitly assigned to at all.

Comment: But without the `Map`, it will not be possible to check for primitives. That was my point. I had actually run into something similar. The approach I had to take was to create a new instance of that class (Which will have default values) and compare new and original object field by field. Another problem which I saw with this approach was that we will have to have all primitives in the Map. because tomorrow someone might add a primitive to the class which didn't exist earlier. But yes, the wrapper approach will definitely work.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar: I'm not sure how anyone could have inferred that from what you said, which was along the lines of "reflection doesn't work for primitive types".

Comment: Edited my comment. Sorry about that

Comment: Which do you think is the better of the 2 approaches?. Use wrapper and compare fields (use *Reflection* to get fields) or creating new instance of class (which will have default values) and then compare field by field?

Comment: @Vinod: I prefer my approach, as it doesn't require you to be able to create a new instance... Don't forget there may be only parameterized constructors etc.

Comment: Yes, parameterized constructors might cause problems. If all primitives are included in the map, then your approach will be better. Thank You

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, but I wanted to check if it has been set or not. I didn't want to use wrapper classes and check for null because then I'd have to change my code in many places. But looks like I have no other choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use objects with default values instead of primitive types; i.e.

```
class MyClass{      
    @JsonProperty("my_boolean")
    private Boolean myBoolean = BOOLEAN_DEFAULT; // get it from a map

    @JsonProperty("my_int")
    private Integer myInt = INT_DEFAULT;  // get it from a map

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Then

```
if (myClass.getMyInt() == null) {
  // The value is explicitly set to null
} else if (defaultValuesMap.get(Integer.class).equals(myClass.getMyInt())) {
  // The value has its default value
} else {
  // etc
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using wrapper classes because I'd have to change my code in many places. But looks like I don't have any other choice.